# Text-to-Speech Service Offering Custom Voice

Tags: api, web-services, speech-synthesis

I would like to use a text-to-speech service using a custom voice to synthesize the output voice of a chatbot. For the custom voice, I have an actor that can record custom scripts. The voice is English with a German accent (intentional). The text-to-speech service should be callable using an API in real-time.

I know that Google, Microsoft, and Amazon Polly offer custom voices for their TTS services (but the prices are not disclosed for training the custom voice).

Does somebody have any recommendations for a text-to-speech service offering training of custom voices in good quality? And what are the prices for training and using the custom voice?

Answer (score 0):

try the Aflorythmic API: https://console.api.audio/

They also create custom voices: Heise Online did this for their Podcast: https://www.heise.de/news/In-eigener-Sache-heise-online-klont-Stimme-von-Podcast-Redakteurin-7255690.html

Comment: Aflorythmic rejected my work email because it supposely wasn't "professional."

Comment: Yes, mine too, maybe their email form is broken. Try another way of contacting them